# Azure EventGridEvent ignores JsonProperty

Tags: c#, json, azure-eventgrid

I send an Event to an Azure EventGrid Topic:

```
public void SendMsg(string eventType, string dataVersion, object payload) {
var cloudEvent = new EventGridEvent("myevent", eventType, dataVersion, payload)
{
  Topic = _configuration.Topic
};
await _client.SendEventAsync(cloudEvent);
}
```

(_client is of Type `EventGridPublisherClient`)

`payload` has the following Content:

```
using NewtonSoft.Json;
public class CuData {
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum CancellationTypes
{
  Regular,
  Special,
  Relocation
}

[JsonProperty("type")]  
public CancellationTypes CancellationType {get;set;}
}
```

Now the event contains something like this:

```
{
"CancellationType":0
}
```

but *should* be something like

```
{
"type":"Regular"
}
```

so is ignoring the Json-Properties from the NewtonSoft.Json-NameSpace. How can I tell the EventGridEvent to use my Json-Configuration?

I also tried  `[DataMember(Name ="type")]` instead of `[JsonProperty]` with no success either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use another constructor on EventGridEvent using BinaryData and therefore being able to provide JsonSerialize-Options:

```
var serOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
  PropertyNamingPolicy = null
};
serOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
var binaryData=new BinaryData(payload, serOptions);
var cloudEvent = new EventGridEvent("lichtblick/serviceView", eventType, dataVersion, binaryData)
{
  Topic = _configuration.Topic
};
```

(the null forcing PascalCasing instead of camelCasing)

Alternatively the properties from `System.Text.Json.Serialization` can be used (`[JsonPropertyName]`etc)